# Make one javascript toggle button turn off another

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript toggle buttons; that toggle some content; and they are next to each other and work independently; the only problem is that I want it so that when you toggle one "div" on; the other one will disappear and vice versa.  Right now if you toggle one and then toggle the other they both show at the same time.  I have tried to change this code myself and cannot figure it out, so I was wondering if anyone knows how to adapt this.  the page is here:  (http://gtdsites.com/1a-toggle-buttons/).

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(btn,a){
    var e1=document.getElementById(a);
    if(!e1)return true;
    if(e1.style.display=="none"){
        e1.style.display="block";

        btn.value = "MENU";
    }
    else{
        e1.style.display="none";
        btn.value = "MENU";
    }
    return true;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe1(btn,a2){
    var e2=document.getElementById(a2);
    if(!e2)return true;
    if(e2.style.display=="none"){
        e2.style.display="block";

        btn.value = "CART";
    }
    else{
        e2.style.display="none";
        btn.value = "CART";
    }
    return true;
}
</script>


<div id="mobile_buttons_cont">
  <input class="mobile_buttons" type="button" onclick="return toggleMe(this,'gman123')"
         value="MENU" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="mobile_buttons" type="button" onclick="return toggleMe1(this,'gman124')"
         value="CART">
</div>

<div id="gman123" style="display: none">
  <br/>
  <ul class="gsites_header2">
    <li class="gsites_header2">
      <a href="/contact/">CONTACT</a>
    </li>

    <li class="gsites_header2">
      <a href="/services/">SERVICES</a>
    </li>

    <li class="gsites_header2">
      <a href="/index/">INDEX</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="gman124" style="display: none">
  <br/>
  <?php
     echo do_shortcode('[do_widget id=cart66cartwidget-2]');
  ?>

</div>
```

Comment: This code works for me (GC30).

Comment: I don't understand why you set `btn.value`, since you're setting it to the value it already has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions are nearly identical, you can combine them by making the button value a parameter. And to toggle the other DIV, pass its ID as another parameter.

```
<script>
function toggleMe(btn,btnval,thisdiv,otherdiv){
    var e1=document.getElementById(thisdiv);
    var e2=document.getElementById(otherdiv);
    if(!e1 || !e2) {
        return true;
    }
    if(e1.style.display=="none"){
        e1.style.display="block";
        e2.style.display="none";
    } else {
        e1.style.display="none";
        e2.style.display="block";
    }
    btn.value = btnval;
    return true;
}
</script>

<div id="mobile_buttons_cont">
  <input class="mobile_buttons" type="button" onclick="return toggleMe(this, 'MENU', 'gman123', 'gman124')"
         value="MENU" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="mobile_buttons" type="button" onclick="return toggleMe1(this, 'CART', 'gman124', 'gman123')"
         value="CART">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much barmar; i got this to work; had to modify a tiny bit but could not have done this by myself! all the best, G

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way to do this would be to just set the display of the other one to `'none'` whenever you open one. For example, you could just add this line of code `document.getElementById(a2).display='none';` above `e1.style.display="block";`.

If you wanted to be more robust, or if you're doing this with a lot of divs, you have a couple of options. You could put all your divs in an array and check them for whether they're open (or just set them all to `display='none'` if it doesn't slow you down to much). You could also create an array with the open one and `push` and `splice` them as needed. I think ultimately, though, you'd be best served by changing the CSS class of a div based on whether it's showing, and that way you can find the shown element(s) quickly using `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way of doing this with jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()`.

I got rid of your functions and replaced them with jQuery I also gave the buttons id's to make selecting them easier. I've also given you 2 examples of the `.show()` and `.hide()` method.

```
`$("#btn_1").click(function(){
$("#btn_2").hide();
});
$("#btn_2").click(function(){
$("#btn_1").hide(); 
});
$("#btn_3").click(function(){
$("#btn_3").hide();
});
$("#btn_4").click(function(){
$("#btn_4").hide(); 
});`
```

here's the working demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanhagz/rFp7w/

Comment: Hello Ryan: I looked at this and I would love to try it but so far I have had no luck getting jqery to run on a wordpress page; so if you have any tips on that to share I would appreciate it...all the best,  G

Comment: Not sure how it works with Wordpress, but to include jQuery into a normal webpage you add a script tag in your header like this: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​ It will probably be similar, but look up how to include jquery into wordpress. :) EDIT: from the quick search I did, it seems about the same as any other webpage. if you want your code to be executed after the page loads add this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {//code goes here});` source: [Jquery with Wordpress](http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress)